# What is a client key and how to generate one?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I'm trying to send an https request to a server using Java. The URL to which I'm connecting needs the clientkey.

The URL is: "https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/"+clientKey+"/info.json/" + zipcode + "/radians";

How would I get the client key?

Comment: https://www.zipcodeapi.com/Plans

Answer (score 2):

I think so you need to register on this website to generate a client key , basically these keys are like an access token to the web services you want to consume.

You can register but as the website says **"free account allows up to 50 API requests per hour. Complete this form to get an API key to start using the API**"

https://www.zipcodeapi.com/Register